# Refresh token for google adwords getting expire after 7 days

Tags: oauth2-playground

I am using the platform Oauth Playground to generate Access token and Refresh token for purpose of using it in LSA API(google Local Service Ads API).

Where I am using Refresh token to generate new access token as it is used for connecting with api service Which is successfully done, But the Refresh Token is getting expire after 7 days. I am trying to automate the code so If it is possible to extend Refresh token expiration.